# Unable to simply install and use datatable editor (laravel 9/npm)

Tags: laravel, npm, datatable

I end up posting this message because I spent my entire day trying to get the datatable editor to work but without success.

I'm on a brand new install of laravel 9 that I haven't installed anything on. I just set up datatable on USER table and it's ok.

But when i want to use datatable editor (I bought the license today) i have this two error in the console :smile:

> app-e6e82434.js:45 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor
> at HTMLDocument. (http://test88.test/users:67:75)
> at Q (http://test88.test/build/assets/app-e6e82434.js:45:31424)
> at ae (http://test88.test/build/assets/app-e6e82434.js:45:31749) undefined>

> Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor
> at HTMLDocument. (users:67:75)
> at Q (app-e6e82434.js:45:31424)
> at ae (app-e6e82434.js:45:31749)>

I installed datatable editor via npm then ran the script so that it puts the files in the right place as shown in the doc
but I have the impression that it does not take into account my files or that it considers that I do not have a license.

I installed the debug script but the link it sends me always gives a 404. The debug script crashes when I'm on the page that tries to display the table of users and when I'm on a classic page it shows me that everything is ok except that datatable editor is not loaded.

I think I've tried everything to load this damn script but I can't. Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

I try to make datatable editor running

Comment: Which database editor you are talking about? are you talking about **yajra db editor?**

Comment: yes it's yajra editor